# PropType shape - throws error on declaration

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

I am creating a shape object for one of my component. but getting error on compile. I am much new to `reactjs` any one help me here?

here is my declaration: the way i declare is wrong, please help me with correct approach.

```
function Tweet({tweet}) {
    return (
        <div className="tweet">
            <Avatar hash={tweet.gravatar} />
            <div className="content">
                <NameWithHandle author={tweet.author} /> <Time time={tweet.timestamp} />
                <Message text={tweet.message} />
                <div className="buttons">
                    <ReplyButton />
                    <RetweetButton count={tweet.retweets} />
                    <LikeButton count={tweet.likes} />
                    <MoreOptionsButton />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


Tweet.PropTypes.shape({

    message:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    gravatra:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    author:PropTypes.shape({
        handle:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        name:PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }),
    likes:PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    retweets:PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    timestamp:PropTypes.string.isRequired

})


var testTweet = {
    message: "Something about cats.",
    gravatar: "xyz",
    author: {
    handle: "catperson",
    name: "IAMA Cat Person"
    },
    likes: 2,
    retweets: 0,
    timestamp: "2016-07-30 21:24:37"
}
```

getting error as :

```
index.js:106 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shape' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PropTypes`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes) define `shape` validators .

`Tweet`  Compnent  object's property `shape` should be defined using `propTypes` property

It should be.

```
Tweet.propTypes  = {

    someObj : PropTypes.shape({

        message:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        gravatra:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        author:PropTypes.shape({
            handle:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            name:PropTypes.string.isRequired
        }),
        likes:PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        retweets:PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        timestamp:PropTypes.string.isRequired

    })
 }
```

Comment: Did you imported `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`